# Is Save the machine state same as Saving then power off in virtualbox?

Tags: dns, active-directory, virtualbox

Now this is the issue that I have. I need to join my Windows 7 user to Windows Server 2019 Active Directory Domain in VM. But then I'm not sure whether this could work if the Windows Server 2019 is powered off and the server is still working. If yes, I can't ping the Windows Server's ip address from my Windows 7 user cause I can't run 2 different Windows in VM. I tried to use "Save the machine state" in order to keep the server running. So I don't know if "Save the Machine state" is actually like "Sleep". And if the server domain name could be joined when the server is powered off, I can't ping the domain name from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here but if you want to join the Window 7 WM to the Domain of the Server you need both of them to be running and then log on to the Domain with a privileged domain user.
Anyways savin the state is not the same as power off.